# not able to implement call.enqueue using retrofit

Tags: retrofit2

this is the part where it's not working. i'm trying to fetch data from a sever using retrofit. i have created api interface. which will establish connection and in the fragment where i have to retrieve data implementing that but it doesn't work. the android studio is not able to resolve call.enqueue() .

```
    call.enqueue (new Callback<List<Student>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Student> call, Response<List<Student>> response) {

        List<Student> studata = response.body();


    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Student>> call, Throwable t) {
        Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Please be specific about your server response(is it an **object/array**), if the error is `not able to resolve call.enqueue()`, you probable haven't added retrofit dependency in `build.gradle`

Comment: yes it's an object/array. i have included following dependencies  compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.2.0'

Comment: You should use the same versions for your base retrofit and your converter.  So 2.3.0 for both.

Answer (score 0):

Check your imports at the top of that file.  Make sure your import for `Call` is

```
import retrofit2.Call;
```

and not `import okhttp3.Call;` or `import android.telecom.Call;` or some other random `Call`.

Comment: i'm using import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;    still getting error

Comment: Then the only other thing I can think of is a misplaced '}' or ')'. Is that the only error you are seeing or is there more "Unable to resolve x" errors?

Answer (score 0):

In your interface, change the return type of the method to `Call<your-return-type>`.